# qtip (jquery plugin to show tooltips): trying to work with it

Tags: jquery, plugins, tooltip

Im trying to operate [qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/). i have this code

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src='/home/javier/Scaricati/jquery-qtip-1.0.0-rc3080111/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$().ready(function() { $('div.foo').qtip({

}) ); 

</script>

<div title="jander" class="foo">hola</div>


</body>
</html>
```

When i go to the div it just shows the HTML tooltip (containing "jander" of course).

I have checked the .js are loaded.

Im still a newbie with jquery and tooltips so any idea will be welcome.

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$(function() { //shortcut for document ready
    $('div.foo').qtip({
        content: {
            text: false // Use each elements title attribute
        }
    });
});
```